# Отсутствие поддержки новых типов тега input в Firefox

Tags: firefox, html5

Почему в Firefox, который является одним из передовых браузеров, практически полностью отсутствует поддержка новых типов тега input (таких как datetime, date, time, range, color и др)? В гугле ответа на этот вопрос не нашлось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что ещё не успели заимплементировать?

Вот [эта таблица](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML5%29) говорит, что остальные браузеры тоже не сильно впереди.

Вот наверное [прямой ответ](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/928599) на ваш вопрос от разработчиков:

> Спецификация html5 сама по себе до сих пор полностью не стандартизована и может меняться. Так что невозможно окончательно ответить на ваш вопрос. html5 покамест просто модное название для новых технологий веба.

Comment: В случае с новыми типами инпута Опера оказалась впереди всех.

Comment: @Heidel: да, Опера всегда старалась быть впереди.

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуй это только компании Mozilla известно.

Но html5 пока еще полностью не утвержден толком и далеко не всеми браузерами поддерживается. 
Кстати говоря вот [здесь](http://caniuse.com/#search=input%20type) можете посмотреть поддержку браузерами input'ов html5

Comment: Понятно.
По новым типам инпутов вот по это ссылке еще хорошо смотреть, что кем поддерживается http://www.miketaylr.com/code/input-type-attr.html